# Is this a valid proof that a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors is a basis of an inner product space $V$ with dimension $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'll be using bra-ket notation as my proof requires using inner products and those come out natural in this notation. It goes as follows:

Let $\Omega$ be a set of $n$ vectors $|v_i\rangle \in V$ where $V$ is an inner product space of dimension $n$. Assume $\Omega$ does not form a basis of $V$. Then we can extend the set into $\Omega + |w\rangle$ where $|w\rangle$ is an arbitrary vector of $V$ that is not in $\Omega$. Then:

$$\langle w|w\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \langle w|v_i\rangle .$$

Simply stating that an arbitrary number can be written as a linear combination of others. But this follows from the equality:

$$|w\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i |v_i\rangle . $$

Therefore $\Omega$ spans $V$ and therefore it's a basis.

Comment: Dear @agaminon , if $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space, then every colection of $n$ linear independent vector is a basis. We don't need the inner product to prove it.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta I know, but I was doing a problem that required proving this for completeness and I forgot the proof for the simple vector space. However the problem was within an inner product space and therefore I came up with this proof. Thank you

Comment: I suggest making more of an effort to use *mathematical* notation in a mathematics forum, not physics notation.

Comment: You never assumed $\Omega$ was a linearly independent set. So the next step is not valid. Nor the next step, either way.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, yeah that was a miss on my part. But then, why is the next step not valid even if you assume $\Omega$ is linearly independent?

Comment: You want the extended set linearly independent, and yet your $\langle w,w\rangle$ formula assumes $w$ is in their span.

Comment: Well $\langle w|w \rangle$ should be able to be written in that way as $|w\rangle$ is not orthogonal to $|v_i\rangle$ in general, and so it's just writing a complex number as a sum of other complex numbers. I don't see why this assumes $|w\rangle$ is in the span.